# Konvajs Delete canvas not working , Instead it just clears canvas

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

I am trying to delete canvas. For that I have used below 2lines of code

```
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);**
```

This is just clearling the canvas, but on click on that canvas its reshowing same data.

The canvas is not deleted, but temporary hidden on clear.

Answer (score 2):

`Konva` is a scene graph for your canvas. The scene has nodes, such as `Layer`, `Group`, `Shape`.

You don't need to clear the canvas element manually. You just need to destroy all nodes from the scene. Like this:

```js
layer.destroyChildren();
layer.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this too.Thats also not working.

I tried below code and thats working fine.

**var stage_main = this.$refs.stage.getStage();

```
         stage_main.clear();

            Object.keys(this.canvasElements).forEach((key) => {
                this.canvasElements[key]= [];
            });**
```

I also need to clear canvaselement object along with stage clear